# What is the correct way to have a method return a dummy promise with Bluebird in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

So, I have a function with a chain of promises like this:

```
Myclass.Prototype.initAsync = function() {
  someFunctionAsync(params).bind(this)
    .then(function(data) {
      processData(data);
      return someOtherFunctionAsync(params).bind(this);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      processData(data);
      return yetAnotherFunctionAsync(params).bind(this);
    })
    .finally(function(data) {
      processData(data);
    });
 }
```

It works, but I want this function itself to be able to be in a chain of promises. Normally, I'd just get rid of the "finally" at the end, but I don't want the caller to be responsible for calling processData. I want to be able to call this function like this:

```
setupFunctionAsync(params).bind(this)
  .then(function(data) {
    processSetup();
    return initAsync();
  })
  .finally(function(data) {
    runProgram();
  });
```

In the "finally" of initAsync, what is the proper thing to do? Do I want to create a new empty promise with Promise.new and return that? Or do I want to use Promise.method with an empty method? Or is there a better way?

Right now I am doing the following but I wonder if this is the best thing to do:

```
return someFunctionAsync(params).bind(this)
   .then(function(data) {
...
   .then(function(data) {
     processData(data);
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(); });
   });
```

---

NEWEST UPDATE:

After reading some of the answers, will this work?

```
Myclass.Prototype.initAsync = function() {
  return someFunctionAsync(params).bind(this)
    .then(function(data) {
      processData(data);
      return someOtherFunctionAsync(params).bind(this);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      processData(data);
      return yetAnotherFunctionAsync(params).bind(this);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      processData(data);
    });
  }
```

and it is called like:

```
this.initAsync()
  .then(function() {
    runProgram();
  });
```

Notice that I don't have a "return" in the last then of initAsync. Is that ok?

Comment: Why not change that `finally` into another `then`?

Comment: jperezov can you be more specific as to what you mean. Do you mean like what I did above?

Comment: Yeah I don't see anything wrong with that. Alternatively, you could make `processData` a function that returns a promise, which would allow you to do `return processData()` in all of your function calls. You can chain off of that as well.

Comment: Your `.initAsync()` has inner returns but no outer return - the opposite mistake made by most people.

Comment: on an unrelated note, `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(); })` can be reduced to `Promise.resolve()`...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put, Roamer-1888, that in the real version it is "return someFunctionAsync(params).bind(this)" so that it can return the promise chain to the parent so that it can continue with the chain. (The parent calls this.initAsync().then( ... etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding `finally`. The function passed to `finally` is invoked in any case, this means both, when the promise is resolved and when it is rejected. `finally` also returns another promise (having the value of the previous promise), so chaining is no problem.

It looks a lot like you should be using `then` and you are only using `finally` because it seems a good fit for the last step in the process. You can just use `then` here.

Anyway, since `finally` already returns a promise you can just add a `return` at the beginning of your function. You don't need a "dummy promise".

Not having a return statement in the function passed ot the last `then` is not a problem. It just means that no value is passed to the next promise chained after the `then`. However, it will be called anyway. The code you added to your question looks just fine.

Comment: Actually, I got burned by this. I didn't realize the "finally" was always called. I don't know why I assumed it wasn't. The full version of this code had a "catch" segment too and I had assumed that if the catch was called, then finally wasn't.

Anyways, you are saying I can just "return someFunctionAsync(params).bind(this) ... etc." and I don't need a "return" in the finally block at all?  I guess its like a "then" block without a return, but that you still want to chain on to the next then block? Does that work?

Comment: I updated my question to more clearly say what I was trying to say in the previous comment as it is easier to format code there.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer to answer the question you added.